# Unable to dial SIP phone connected to 3CX system via Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip

So i have a rather complicated issue I am trying to connect my Asterisk with a client 3cx phone system

So there is a sip phone connected to 3cx system with extension `351`

On my Asterisk I have added client 3cx system to sip.conf as follows:

```
[3cx]
type=friend
host=151.236.XX.XXX
username=400
secret=secret
context=main
canreinvite=no
;authname=authname
;fromuser=fromuser
;fromdomain=fromdomain
insecure=port,invite
trustrpid=yes
disallow=all
allow=alaW
```

In my extensions.conf i have following line

```
exten => _X.,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@3cx,,ro)
```

However when it attempts to dial 'SIP/351@3cx' using landline that routes to my asterisk I am getting the following output

```
[Oct  4 20:05:22] VERBOSE[22119] chan_sip.c:
<--- SIP read from UDP:151.236.XX.XXX:5060 --->
SIP/2.0 404 User unknown.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 85.13.XXX.XXX:5060;branch=z9hG4bK17f3106e
To: <sip:351@151.236.XX.XXX>;tag=9e38f119
From: "+442084526XXX"<sip:+442084526XXX@85.13.XXX.XXX>;tag=as33bb12fb
Call-ID: 5cc7443b00658b746ff822895e557d3c@85.13.XXX.XXX:5060
CSeq: 103 INVITE
User-Agent: 3CXPhoneSystem 14.0.49169.513 (48654)
Content-Length: 0
```

However I have downloaded a soft phone (MicroSIP) to my desktop and registered ths soft phone directly with client 3cx system. When i dial 351 I am connected straight to the agent.

I was looking online for solutions and i have found that adding `register` to sip.conf (so essentially i register my asterisk as sip phone to 3cx system) should help but it did not work.

my `sip.conf` register entry:

```
register => 400:secret@151.236.XX.XXX
```

I am slightly lost here so any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add the `fromdomain=<your 3x domain>` and `qualify=yes` to your `sip.conf`, and it's `type=peer` for your task. `Final sip.conf`

```
register=>400:secret@151.236.XX.XXX/from-3cx

[3cx]
type=peer
dtmfmode=rfc2833
insecure=port,invite
qualify=yes
canreinvite=no
directmedia=yes
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=g729
defaultuser=400
secret=secret
context=from-3cx

[phone-connected-to-asterisk]
type=friend
host=dynamic
transport=udp
secret=secret
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
context=from-asterisk
insecure=port,invite
```

And make sure to add incoming context to your `extensions.conf`. Final `extensions.conf`:

```
[general]
static=yes
writeprotect=yes
clearglobalvars=yes

[default]
include => incoming

[incoming]
include => from-3cx

[from-asterisk]
exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@3cx,45)

[from-3cx]
exten => _X.,1,Progress()
exten => _X.,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},60,gt)
exten => _X.,n,Hangup()
```

Comment: Yup that fromdomain parameter did the trick. Thank you :)